# How can I drag a UICollectionViewCell from one UICollectionView to another UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am making an iPad application. On one page of this application, there is a UICollectionView on the left-hand side and another UICollectionView on the right hand side. Each UICollectionView is one column wide.

The functionality I desire is as follows:
Each UICollectionViewCell on the left hand side should be able to be dragged to the UICollectionView on the right hand side. If this is not possible, then at least a UICollectionViewCell should be able to be dragged out of the left UICollectionView and then I'll handle having it appear in the righthand UICollectionView.

Is this functionality possible? If so, how would I go about implementing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to actually 'pass' a cell from a collection to the other, but you can do the following:

1) Once you detect that the user dragged a cell in the other collection, delete the cell from the first collection (let's call it Collection 1). You can maybe use a nice fade animation to make the cell disappear.

2) Add a cell to the second table with a nice animation (see the UICollectionView and UICollectionViewLayout methods and delegate methods for this).

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. How could I go about implementing having drag-able cells? Would I need to use something like [LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout](https://github.com/lxcid/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout) or is there a simpler resource that you could point me to? Thanks.

Comment: You can either use this LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout, which will also allow you to sort the cells with gestures, or simply add a UIPanGestureRecognizer to your collection, when the gesture begins get the cell at the touch point (UICollectionView has a method for that), then when the user drags the cell around move it accordingly. When the gesture ends or is cancelled you can check the cell's position and act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks again, that second option sounds like exactly what I'm looking for and also fairly easy to implement.

Comment: You're welcome. Since I've noticed that you're pretty new to the community, I just want to make you notice that you can 'accept' an answer and as your reputation grows you'll also get some privileges. One of the first you'll get is to 'upvote' good answers or 'downvote' bad ones. Feel free to accept my answer if you liked it ;)

Answer (score 6):

You would want to attach a long press gesture recognizer to the common superview of both collectionViews.  The drag operation is triggered by the long-press, and the entire transaction is handled within that recognizer.  Because the pan gesture is used for scrolling the collectionviews, you will run into problems in trying to use the pan recognizer.

The key thing is the gesture recognizer needs to be attached the COMMON superview, and all points and rectangles are converted to the coordinate system of the superview.

This isn't the exact code (this moves from a CV to another view) but the process would be similar (NOTE: I have tried to strip out some code that would be irrelevant to your app, so I could have messed something up in the process -- but the concept holds):

```
- (void) processLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
{
    if (!dragView)
        return;
    CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint translation;
    translation.x = location.x - dragViewStartLocation.x;
    translation.y = location.y - dragViewStartLocation.y;
    CGAffineTransform theTransform = dragView.transform;
    theTransform.tx = translation.x;
    theTransform.ty = translation.y;
    dragView.transform = theTransform;
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:dragView];
    return;
}   

if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
    //  if point gives a valid collectionView indexPath we are doing a long press on a picture item to begin a drag
    //  & drop operation.
    CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:collectionView];
    dragViewIndexPath = [collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:point];
    if (dragViewIndexPath)  // i.e., selected item in collection view.
    {
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:dragViewIndexPath];
        dragView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:cell.tag];
        [dragView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view addSubview:dragView];
        dragView.center = [collectionView convertPoint:point toView:self.view];
        dragViewStartLocation = dragView.center;
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:dragView];
    }
    return;
}

if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    if (dragView)
    {
        dragView.center = CGPointMake(dragView.center.x + dragView.transform.tx, dragView.center.y + dragView.transform.ty);
        CGAffineTransform theTransform = dragView.transform;
        theTransform.tx = 0.0f;
        theTransform.ty = 0.0f;
        UIView *dropTarget = [self mapDisplayModeToReceiverView];   // get drop target

        CGRect convertedTargetFrame = [self.view convertRect:dropTarget.frame fromView:dropTarget.superview];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(convertedTargetFrame, dragView.center)) // if so, then drop it.
        {
            ImageWithAttachedLabel *i = (ImageWithAttachedLabel *) dragView;
            [speakStrings addObject:[i.labelText stringByAppendingString:@". "]];
            UserData *uData = (UserData *)i.userDataObject;
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:uData.image];
            CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 140.0f, 140.0f);
            ImageWithAttachedLabel *newImage = [[ImageWithAttachedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:newFrame withImage:image withLabel:uData.itemName];
            newImage.tag = RECEIVERVIEW_MAGIC_NUMBER;
            [self.view addSubview:newImage];
            newImage.center = [receiverView convertPoint:dropTarget.center toView:self.view];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35f animations:^{ newImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.15f, 1.15f); newImage.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity; }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished) {  if (finished)
                                                            {
                                                                [newImage removeFromSuperview];
                                                                newImage.frame = newFrame;
                                                                [dropTarget addSubview:newImage];
                                                                [dragView removeFromSuperview];
                                                                dragView=nil; }
                                                            }];

        }
        else
        {
            [dragView removeFromSuperview];
            dragView = nil;
        }

        [self reloadData];
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @regularExpression, Whats dragView in your code?

Comment: Hi, dragView is just a pointer to a UIView that is being dragged.  It is set to the view being dragged in the gesture recognizer "StateBegan" code:

    dragView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:cell.tag]

In this case, the view is the contents of a cell in a collection view, but it really could be any view.